# How to stop corrupting global variable by ISR?

Tags: variables, global-variables, isr

```
volatile UINT16 count = 0;

void triggerTimer( UINT16 pulse_count){

count = pulse_count;
P1DIR |=BIT1;
P1OUT &= ~BIT1;
}

#pragma vector=TIMER0_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer_A(void)
{
 count--;
 P1OUT ^=BIT1;

}
```

On executing above program ,count value getting as 0 sometimes 655336, not the proper value ,so Bit1 is not toggeling ,it stays LOW or HIGH

What is the reason for that? I want to toggle the BIT for particular number of times